# Switching Focus between Jtables Query?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focusmanager

I have two Jtables Emplyoee and Manager.If I enter on Emplyoee Table then focus should go on Manager table.I used ChangeSelection but it is not working.

Comment: selection != focus. Anyway, your question and what you tried is unclear - please show an SSCCE to explain what exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is to attach a key binding to the `Employee` table that moves focus to the `Manager`

Take a look at [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details.

Within your action handler, you would need to call `requestFocusInWindow` using a instance of the `Manager` table.

I did look at the focus sub system, but this would effect the entire focus root, which I felt was beyond the scope of what you were asking.

**Updated**

You could change the focus traversal keys, but this will only move focus to the next focusable component...

```
Set forward = new HashSet(table.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS));
forward.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"));
table.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, forward);
//Set backward = new HashSet(table.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS));
//backward.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift TAB"));
//table.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, backward);
```